# PROC - Multi threading C application oracle 19c

Tags: c, oracle, multithreading, proc, oracle19c

I have a C application that was running perfectly on IBM AIX P7 machine and connecting to oracle 11g, when migrating this application to AIX P9 machine and connecting to 19c, The application keep crashing with core dump.

I have recompiled the application against Oracle 19c.

What is the issue?

Comment: There's a bug in your program which didn't manifest on the old platform. Use gdb to find it out (MALLOCDEBUG=catch_overflow could also help). Also test your program on other platforms, try other compilers with maximum warning-level, use static checkers. (I would also suggest valgrind, if it weren't Oracle. ElectricFence is still an option.)

Comment: There's no any piece of error code/message or a piece of crashing code. Should we guess? Is this possible if you (who may see the error and debug the code) are not able to find the reason?